# How does C compiler treat enum?

Tags: c, enums

`enum` is a user-defined type. In general there are no big differences between `enum` in C and C++. Except for scopes in C++: if some `enum` is declared within function or class it cannot be accessed outside of declared function/class. This is not applicable to C.

There is no difference in declaration.
For example, it is possible to declare new `enum` as follows (for both C and C++):

```
enum newEnum { zero = 0, one, two, three };
```

There is almost no difference in defining new variables.
To define new variable with new defined type it is possible to use the following line:

```
enum newEnum varA = zero; // though allowed to skip enum keyword in C++
```

But there is one interesting point.
In C++ you cannot add two `enum` values and assign the result to `enum`-type variable:

```
varA = one + zero; // won't compile in c++
```

It is explainable: `enum` values can be casted to `int` values, but not vice versa (`int` to `enum`). So in the last example a compiler cannot assign the result of sum (with type of `int`) to varA (`enum` newEnum), because it cannot covert `int` to newEnum.

However it is possible in C: the last code line successfully compiles. This confuses me.
Therefore a question rises: how does C compiler treat `enum`? Is it not even a custom type for it? Is it just `int`?

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#:%7b%7d,enum_declaration

Comment: C simply does nothing to protect you from yourself.

Comment: The enumerators have type `int` in C  .  (the enum type  still exists, just the enumerators don't have that type)

Comment: In C, `enum` is more like a typedef.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C enumerations belong to integer types. From the C Standard (6.2.5 Types)

> 17 **The type char, the signed and unsigned integer types, and the
>   enumerated types are collectively called integer types.** The integer
>   and real floating types are collectively called real types.

In C++ enumerations are not integer types however they can be promoted to integer types.

This is the main difference of C and C++ enumeration types if do not take into account C++ scoped enumerations.

As for this stetement

> if some enum is declared within function or class it cannot be
>   accessed outside of declared function/class. This is not applicable to
>   C.

then it is wrong. An enumeration declared in a block scope (including the function outer-most block) in C is not visible outside this block.

Answer (score 2):

In C the enumeration constants (i.e. the values `zero, one, two, three`) have type `int`.

The type `enum newEnum` also exists, but the enumerators do not have that type.  The type `enum newEnum` is an integer type, and the compiler can choose the size of the type, but it must be at least large enough to hold all of the defined enumerators. In your example its size might be 1, 2, 4, 8, or anything else.

There can be variables and values of the enumerated type, e.g. `enum newEnum x = 3; ++x;`.

The enumerated type participates in implicit integer conversions with a rank according to its size .